# TypeScript generics "extends" constraint: Is there a nullable constraint?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

It looks like the following doesn't compile:

```
interface IServiceBase {};
type INullableServiceBase = IServiceBase | undefined;

public GetService<T extends INullableServiceBase>(): T
{
  return this._service;
}
```

This yields TS2322: Type 'INullableServiceBase' cannot be assigned to type 'T'. Type 'undefined' cannot be assigned to type 'T'.

How can I define a generic constraint to allow nullable types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the caller is the one deciding `T`. If `this._service` is defined to be `IServiceBase | null` you have two problems.

1. `T` might be `IServiceBase` so assigning `IServiceBase | null` is not type safe since `this._service` might be null
2. `T` might be a type derived from `IServiceBase`, (ie `IExtendedServiceBase`). So `this._service` will not satisfy that `T` in any way.

These reasons are enough to make the compiler reject this. You could force things with a type assertion (`this._service as T`), or you might consider not making this generic at all, since the caller is not really in control of `T`:

```
function GetService(): INullableServiceBase
{
  return this._service;
}
```

Or making the containing class generic on the service type:

```
class ServiceFactory<T extends INullableServiceBase> {
    constructor(private _service: T) { }
    public GetService(): T {
        return this._service;
    }
}
```

But without more context it is difficult to say what will work best.

Comment: Actually, I've been using your first suggestion yet. But I wanted to switch over to a generic. However, since the GetService() function is just a minor part of my controller class I would not want to add its type to the class's definition. Thanks a lot for pointing things out!